# Deploy django with Heroku issue, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment

I deployed with Heroku, and I can see my template and everything. But when I register/login.. it gives me `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I believe it is a problem with `wsgi.py` not doing `manage runserver` because when I run `manage runserver` on my VS code, and refresh the website.. then I have connection to the database. I am stuck as to where the error is coming from. Is it `gunicorn`,`settings.py`, or something I'm missing in Procfile?

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

Settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-react-project.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'form',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user123',
        'PASSWORD': 'password123',
        'HOST': 'heroku host',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
         ],
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',)

}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

SITE_ID = 1

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS looks odd. Your website is surely not `'django-react-.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: ah sorry, i was editing, but django-react-project.herokuapp.com is it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your procfile:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

Leave out the --log-file - part. The above is the basic configuration of a procfile according to Heroku. There are other options, but none with the --log-file - at least on the page that I link to:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn